# Serilog loggin nothing

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Hi everyone i have Mcv Api Project and i try to loggin with Serilog, but when i try to invoke my api and logging some text in file/console, its empty, and i can't understand what's wrong

my program.cs

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var seriliogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Configs"))
                .AddJsonFile("settings.json")
                .Build();
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(seriliogConfiguration)
                .CreateLogger();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

my settings json

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:\\Logs\\logs.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and api when i try to exucete logging in file and console

```
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger) =>  _logger = logger;
       
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get() =>_logger.LogInformation("You requested Get()");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `Serilog` is not injected into `Asp.net Core` container. The interface called in the controller is not a `Serilog` method. So the log will not be written to the file. You need to modify `Program.cs`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                var seriliogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Configs"))
                   .AddJsonFile("settings.json")
                   .Build();
                webBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(seriliogConfiguration);

                });
            });
}
```

I add a log in this action.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("This info is in index");

        return Ok();
    }
```

In console.

[image]

In this log file.

[image]